# Insert only the duplicate records from csv in to the Database

Tags: c#, mysql, database, csv

I am working on  working on validating the csv before inserting them in to the database. I have done the piece of inserting them in to the database but not sure how can I validate for duplicate record and insert only the duplicate records in to the database.The Csv looks like below and we can receive the ProdID as duplicates in CSV

```
ProdID,Name,Color,Availability
P01,Product1,Red,Yes
P02,Product2,Blue,Yes
P03,Product3,Yellow,No
P01,Product4,Red,Yes
P04,Product5,Black,Yes
```

The table has five fields and one of the field is is the Duplicate field

```
class Products
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string location = "\Products.csv";
        List<Products> ProductsList= ReadInCSV(location);
        var connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProgConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        // Need to validate them before putting them in to the table 

        string sqlString = "INSERT INTO PRODUCTS (ProdID,Name,Color,Availability,Duplicate) VALUES (@ProdID,@Name,@Color,@Availability,@Duplicate );";
        for (int i = 0; i < ProductsList.Count; i++)
        {
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
            using (MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand(sqlString, conn))
            {
                comm.Parameters.Add("@ProdID", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ProductsList[i].ProdID;
                comm.Parameters.Add("@Name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ProductsList[i].Name;
                comm.Parameters.Add("@Color", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ProductsList[i].Color;
                comm.Parameters.Add("@Availability", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ProductsList[i].Availability;
                comm.Parameters.Add("@Duplicate", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Yes";
                conn.Open();
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure how can I check for the duplicate records in the csv and do an insert only to the records that are duplicate.

Comment: I'm unclear to what you are asking?  Do you want to only insert the distinct record (i.e. excluding duplicates)? Or do you only want to insert the records that are duplicates (and if so, do you want all copies of the duplicates or just a single instance representing the duplicate)?

Comment: Which are “the duplicate records in the csv”? They all look distinct to me.

Comment: @maccettura I just need to insert the duplicate records. Here P01 is repeating and I need to insert only those two records in to the table

Comment: @DourHighArch Just need to look for ProdID and do an insert in to the database if they are repeating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment you only want to insert the two records that are duplicated.  In your example `p01`.

This can be solved with a simple LINQ query:

```
ProductsList.GroupBy(p => p.ProdID).Where(p => p.Count() > 1).SelectMany(x => x);
```

This will group the items by their respective `ProdID`'s, then we select only the instances where the group contains more than one instance.

Use this in place of your for loop:

```
foreach(var prod in ProductsList.GroupBy(p => p.ProdID).Where(p => p.Count() > 1).SelectMany(x => x))
{
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
    using (MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand(sqlString, conn))
    {
        comm.Parameters.Add("@ProdID", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = prod.ProdID;
        comm.Parameters.Add("@Name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = prod.Name;
        comm.Parameters.Add("@Color", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = prod.Color;
        comm.Parameters.Add("@Availability", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = prod.Availability;
        comm.Parameters.Add("@Duplicate", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "Yes";
        conn.Open();
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1dTYDw) to demo

Comment: Thanks. But I am getting error in `prod.ProdID` saying `'bool' does not contain a definition for 'ProdID' and no extension method 'ProdID' accepting a first argument of type 'bool' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` Should I use ProductsList[i].ProdID; instead

Comment: I updated my answer with a working fiddle, my original code wasn't right

Comment: Thanks a ton. Works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add "where @duplicate like 'yes'" in the Query.